# why sql file generated by postgis was different in notepad and pgAdminIII?

Tags: postgis, shapefile, pgadmin-3

When i imported a shapefile which contains some polygons into PostGIS by command line on Win 7, a problem puzzled me:
   The sql file generated by shp2pgsql opened with notePad has the geom (Mutipolygon) value ,however when put this sql file in pgAdminIII, the value was empty..why??some one can help me??

Comment: please give examples of the sql

Comment: I had issues with that before too, and if I remember correctly some coordinate system wouldn't show data in pgAdmin and I have to change it.

Answer (score 4):

PgAdmin has limits on the largest object it can display in a table cells. Large geometries frequently exceed this limit, which results in an "empty" cell, confusing to new users. If you call ST_NPoint(geom) or ST_GeometryType(geom) you can see that the geometry is in fact there, and does have data in it, you just cannot see it in a PgAdmin cell.